# Show price after selected a element in drop list

Tags: php, mysql

Long ago, I search all over the web but I was unable to find a solution that suits me. I have to write what I want the forum to find help that suits me.

To begin, I have a drop-down which offers several choices. Here is the list

```
<Form name = "sellalcatel" form method = "post" action = "traitement.php" onchange = "return vefify ();">
    <Select name = "Alcatel">
        <Option> Please Select <option>
        <Option value = "Alcatel-1230 + ZTE811"> Alcatel 1230 (ZTE 811) </ option>
        <Option value = "Alcatel-1231"> Alcatel 1231 </ option>
        <Option value = "Alcatel-351"> Alcatel 351 </ option>
    </ Select>
    <Li class = "last">
        Country <input type = "text" size = "40">
        <P> Name <INPUT NAME = "Name" SIZE = 40> </ p>
        <P> Enter your Mail <input name = "email" placeholder = "mail@example.com" required> </ p>
        <Input name = "button" type = "submit" value = "unlock"> </ input>
    </ Li>
</ Form>
```

I want that after the selection of the drop-down list to display the price depending on the selection: for example, if the customer chose the first that should show $ 3 usd, if the second Usd $ 4, $ 2 for the third usd so on.

NB ~ I want to recover the money but simply display it without reloading the page, many of the sites proposed to make a BDD but my problem is that I do not know how to put the price in the database and also the attribute to its correct value in the dropdown.

So is there any other solutions to display the price or can I get help or a database like I want to aficher price?

Comment: You can use Javascript to achieve what you want to do in your system. And also, include what you have started, the code you are working on right now. Check this also - [ask].

Comment: Just use plain JavaScript to get the value of the select item that was clicked and display it inside another element. You don't need a server-sided script for this.

Comment: Logan wayne thanks for you answer,my html code dont print in true format

Comment: It's good now.can have a exemple to show the price in this form with javascript ?

Comment: @Babyhay - where do you get the options for your `alcatel` dropdown? Is this fix? And where would you get the corresponding USD value of the selected option?

Comment: Spencer wieczorek , i dont want to show value in quote,i want to show a price

Comment: @logan wayne I want show the price in below the dropdown liste

Comment: I try to do with <span></span> but i dont know how to show price

Comment: sorry if my english is bad so I do not speak English, it is the quality of this forum that requires me to come register

Comment: We already know that you want to show the price depending on the selected options from your dropdown, but what I'm asking is "is the options for your dropdown fix? Or do you get the options from your database? And how about the corresponding price of those options? Where do you suppose to get it?".

Comment: yes, my dropdown working properly, I have not put all the code in the forum because it is long, I already test how to retrieve the selected data, my biggest problem is for display prices, people tell me to create the database but I do not know how to put the price in the database and also assign each award has its model in the value list

Comment: If i know how the price for this droplist, i can do for the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the feature you want for your system, you can use Javascript. But for my answer, we will be using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), which is a Javascript library.

Download jQuery first, then call it in your header:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE THE SRC DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
```

### Option 1:

Lets create a `div` on where we can display the price:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Then lets add an `id` tag on your `select`:

```
<select name="Alcatel" id="alcatel">
```

If your options are fix, you can manually create conditions for each options on your javascript.

```
$(document).on("change", "#alcatel", function(){

    var alcatelval = $(this).val();

    if(alcatelval == 'Alcatel-1230 + ZTE811'){
        $("#result").text('USD 399');
    } else if(alcatelval == 'Alcatel-1231'){
        $("#result").text('USD 299');
    } else if(alcatelval == 'Alcatel-351'){
        $("#result").text('USD 169');
    }

});
```

You can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/b7qnofw6/) for example.

---

### Option 2:

Put all of the options in your database, along with the corresponding prices:

phone_tb:

```
phone_id | brand_id | model | price
---------+----------+-------+--------
    1    |     1    | 1230  |  399
    2    |     1    | 1231  |  299
    3    |     1    | 351   |  169
```

brand_tb:

```
brand_id | brand_desc
---------+------------
    1    |  Alcatel
    2    |  Samsung
    3    |  Apple
```

Then fetch the options for your drop-down, where you can include the price along with the model and description, so you won't have to use Javascript in order to learn the price of a device:

```
<select name="Alcatel" id="alcatel">
<?php

    $stmt = $YourDBConnection->prepare("SELECT a.phone_id, a.model, a.price, b.brand_desc FROM phone_tb a LEFT JOIN brand_tb b ON a.brand_id = b.brand_id");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($phoneid, $model, $price, $brand);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<option value="'.$phoneid.'">'.$brand.'-'.$model.' - '.price.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();

?>
</select>
```

Comment: If i want to show a one price after select an element in ther liste,a one price for all element in the liste,how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to use javascript.

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1.00">$1.00</option>
  <option value="12.43">$12.43</option>
  <option value="37.21">$37.21</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; // The value
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; // The text
```

Or jQuery:

```
$("#dropdown :selected").text(); // The text
$("#dropdown").val(); // The value
```

The `data` attribute allows you to add custom data to a HTML element.

E.G

HTML

```
<option data-price="12" value="1.00">$1.00</option>
```

Jquery

```
$(this).data("price")
```

Comment: @Ryan the problem is that I'll lose the selected model, there are models that have the same price. I want to display a price that is within the value and depends on the model name that are in the list

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan